# How to assign "addGlobalError()" to correct form if several forms exists

Tags: forms, jsf-2, omnifaces

I have a login and a register form on one and the same page and I try to return the global error message only on the concerning form. How to I do that correctly?

```java
import org.omnifaces.util.Messages;

// login class submit()
Messages.addGlobalError('Login failed');

// register class submit()
Messages.addGlobalError('Register failed');
```

```xhtml
<h:form id="login-form">    
    <h:messages globalOnly="true" />    
    // [...]                            
    <h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{login.submit()}" />    
</h:form>    
<h:form id="register-form">    
    <h:messages globalOnly="true" />    
    // [...]                            
    <h:commandButton value="Sign up" action="#{register.submit()}" />    
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a contradictory... you simply never assign a global error to a specific component (the form **is** a component).

1. Simply make an error that you assign to the **`id`** of the form by using

   ```
   Messages.addError(id, error);
   ```
2. add a `<h:message for="...">` where the for contains the **`id`** of the form.

---

*Here is how your example should look like:*

```java
import org.omnifaces.util.Messages;

// login class submit()
Messages.addError('login-form', 'Login failed');

// register class submit()
Messages.addError('register-form', 'Register failed');
```

```xhtml
<h:form id="login-form">    
    <h:messages globalOnly="true" for="login-from" />    
    // [...]                            
    <h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{login.submit()}"/>    
</h:form>    
<h:form id="register-form">    
    <h:messages globalOnly="true" for="register-from" />    
    // [...]                            
    <h:commandButton value="Sign up" action="#{register.submit()}"/>    
</h:form>
```

Comment: That's what I thought! After google (what I should have done in first place...) I found that nice explanation: http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Messages

Comment: @wittich: Thanks for improving the answer!. But are you sure the `globalOnly="true"` should be there? Sounds contradictory

Comment: You're welcome! Thx for the right clue! About the `globalOnly` I'm not sure, but it works with it correctly... Though it makes probably sense to used it only in one `h:message` or in one additional one... but remove it from your answer, if you think that is the better way!